# About appropriate use of prepared statements in JDBC template in Spring

Tags: java, spring, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am using JDBC template and trying to read data from mysql database by using prepared statements to update data. 
I found two functions [`PreparedStatementCreator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementCreator.html) and [`PreparedStatementSetter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html) are available for displaying data and both of them are created with anonymous inner classes. However, inside the PreparedStatementSetter class, I do not have access to the values I want to set in the prepared statement.
I am using prepared statements to bind the variables as below:

```
PreparedStatement updateNames = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE TBL_STUDENT SET STUDENT_NAME = ? WHERE STUDENT_ID LIKE ? ");

updateNames.setString(1, "Ramchandra"); 

updateNames.setInt(2, 65); 

updateNames.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Just use the [`JdbcTemplate.update`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method. Internally `PreparedStatement` instances are used no need to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for great support.